# How to traverse specific folders

Tags: go

I have following directory structure

```
Root
   |
   |-- dev 
   |     | 
   |     +- files, subdirectory within dev
   |-- prod
   |     |
   |     +- files, subdirectory within prod 
   |-- .git
   |     |
   |     +- .git directory structure
   |--CODEOWNER (file)
   |--README (file)
```

I want to traverse all files in dev and prod.

I tried doing the following

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir("./")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, val := range files {
    // To handle codeowner and readme
    if !val.isDir(){
       continue
    }

   // To handle .git
   if val.Name() == ".git"{
     continue
   }
    err := filepath.Walk(val, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
     // Traverse dircectory , subdirectories and files
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this? My only requirement is "I want to traverse top-level directory(dev and prod) in root directory other than directory starting with a dot(.)

To be more clear:

- In output I want

  - All files, directories, subdirectories of dev
  - All files, directories, subdirectories of prod
- what I do not want

  - Any director of root other than dev and prod (like .git)
  - Any files of root (like codeowner or readme)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filepath.Glob`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob).

This gets all files in the `foo` directory, relative to your working directory:

```
matches, err := filepath.Glob("./foo/*")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

for _, match := range matches {
    fmt.Printf("Got match: %s\n", match)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_WZJAmnhUPt)

In your case, you'd use `filepath.Glob("./dev/*")` and `filepath.Glob("./prod/*")`. Go's implementation doesn't support the "double-star directive" for recursive globs though, so you will have to handle subdirectories yourself.